# How to make frame ticks' labels have same number of digits after decimal point?

Tags: plotting, formatting, precision-and-accuracy, ticks

I'm making the ticks labels of my plot using the rule:

```
FrameTicks -> {{N@FindDivisions[{Min@data1, Max@data2}, 6], None},
    {Range[1960, 2015, 10], None}}
```

This is generating the ticks I want on both axes pretty well. The only problem is that the y-axis ticks vary in the number of decimal places, which I do not want. Is there a way to make all those numbers have the same number of decimal places as the one with the most decimal places?

I wanted to use something like `NumberForm[ticks, {∞, n}]` with `ticks` being the `N@..., 6]` above, but I'm not sure what `n` should be to just go with the tick mark with the most decimal places.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, generate the ticks and their labels with whatever range is desired.

```
ticks[min_, max_] := Module[{d = FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6], n}, 
    n = Ceiling@Log10@Max@Denominator@d; {#, NumberForm[#, {∞, n}]} & /@ N@d]
```

For instance,

```
t = ticks[.01,.03]
(* {{0.01, NumberForm[0.01, {∞, 3}]}, {0.015, NumberForm[0.015, {∞, 3}]}, 
    {0.02, NumberForm[0.02, {∞, 3}]}, {0.025, NumberForm[0.025, {∞, 3}]}, 
    {0.03, NumberForm[0.03, {∞, 3}]}} *)
```

(The `Output` actually looks like [image] .)

They can then be used as, for instance,

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, .04}, Ticks -> {Automatic, t}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Then my only issue is generating that number (n, or 3) of decimal places. This is actually inside a loop that generates 36 graphs; how can I automate determining how many decimal places to make? Some graphs need 2, 3, or 4 decimal places.

Comment: @user3769181,  `n` is computed in the function `ticks`.  (Or, do I misunderstand your comment?)

Comment: I think maybe I just didn't understand what's happening in the function. It's starting to make sense; what is `#` doing?

Comment: @user3769181  The function `{#, NumberForm[#, {∞, n}]} & /@ N@d` maps each element of `N@d` (which is a list of the locations of the ticks), into a list of locations and formatted tick labels (the list of pairs enclosed in `(*  *)` in the answer).  Review the documentation of `Map` for details.  Later, `Plot` puts each tick label at the corresponding tick location.  Review the documentation of `Ticks` for details.

Comment: Alright, fantastic. This works well. Thank you so much!