# Multiple issues using NumberForm with Ticks in version 11.0

Tags: plotting, bugs, front-end, ticks, display

**Bugs introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1; fixed in 11.2.**

With

```
$Version
(* "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)" *)
```

I encountered multiple issues when using `NumberForm` to set the displayed accuracy of tick labels as part of an answer to question [125996](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125996/1063).

```
ticks[min_, max_] := Module[{d = FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6], n}, 
    n = Ceiling@Log10@Max@Denominator@d; {#, NumberForm[#, {∞, n}]} & /@ N@d];
t = ticks[.01, .03];
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, .04}, Ticks -> {Automatic, t}, AspectRatio -> 1];
```

produces the plot in the previous answer, as desired.  However, it should be possible to produce the same plot with

```
sicks[min_, max_] := Module[{d = FindDivisions[{min + .01, max - .01}, 6], n}, 
    n = Ceiling@Log10@Max@Denominator@d; {#, NumberForm[#, {∞, n}]} & /@ N@d]
Plot[x, {x, 0, .04}, Ticks -> {Automatic, sicks}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

However, it instead generates

[image]

along with error messages

> NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification {∞, 3.} should be a positive integer or a pair of positive integers.

Evidently, `NumberForm` failed because `Plot` somehow converted `3` to `3.` in the second argument of `NumberForm`.  (Replacing `n` by `HoldComplete@3` gives the same result.)  In addition, the range of ticks is wrong, which can be explained in part by adding `Print[min, "  ", max, "  ", n]` to `sicks`.  It then also prints `0  0.0422222  3`, showing that `Plot` is not passing the correct value of `max`.

Note that with

```
$Version
(* "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" *)
```

the `NumberForm` error does not occur, but `Plot` still passes the wrong value of `max`.

It is natural to ask how, say, `Plot3D` behaves.

```
Plot3D[25 x y, {x, 0, .04}, {y, 0, .04}, Ticks -> {{0, .04}, {0, .04}, sicks}]
```

[image]

does not generate error messages, but it does not display the correct ticks either (either range or displayed accuracy).

As an aside,

```
AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks]
```

generates `NumberForm` error messages and does not return the tick values shown in the plot, `p`. In contrast, When applied to the 3D plot, `Absolute Options` does not produce error messages, but neither does it return the tick values.

```
(* {Ticks -> {{0., 0.04}, {0., 0.04}, sicks}} *)
```

My questions are, which of these are bugs, and are there workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

As of version 11.2.0, all number formatting functions received the `NHoldRest` attribute:

```
Attributes /@ {NumberForm, ScientificForm, EngineeringForm, 
  PaddedForm, AccountingForm, DecimalForm}
```

> ```
> {{NHoldRest, Protected}, {NHoldRest, Protected}, {NHoldRest, Protected}, 
>  {NHoldRest, Protected}, {NHoldRest, Protected}, {NHoldRest, Protected}}
> ```

The ticks range issue is also fixed:

```
Reap[Rasterize@
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Ticks -> {Sow[{##}, "XTicksRange"] &, Sow[{##}, "YTicksRange"] &}], _, List][[2]]

First@AbsoluteOptions[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], PlotRangePadding]
```

> ```
> {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0215054, 1.05376}}}}
>
> PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}
> ```

Hence both the issues are fixed in version 11.2.0.

---

---

### The `NumberForm::iprf` issue

It is certainly a bug introduced in version 11.0.0. This bug affects internal ticks generating function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` which also uses `NumberForm`:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][0, 1] // Take[#, 3] & // InputForm
```

> ```
> {{0., 0, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.2, NumberForm[0.2, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.4, NumberForm[0.4, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}}
> ```

One workaround is to convert `NumberForm` into string by applying `ToString`. But more general solution is to set `NHoldRest` attribute for `NumberForm`:

```
SetAttributes[NumberForm, NHoldRest]
```

After this change the issue disappear and the following code works without errors in *Mathematica* 11.0.0:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]]
```

---

### The ticks range issue in *Mathematica* 11.0.0

As to the ticks range, it is interesting to compare them in different versions of *Mathematica* using my [`Rasterize` trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280):

```
Reap[Rasterize@
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Ticks -> {Sow[{##}, "XTicksRange"] &, Sow[{##}, "YTicksRange"] &}], _, List][[2]]
```

For comparison it is important to take into account the default value of `PlotRangePadding` which can be obtained as follows:

```
First@AbsoluteOptions[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], PlotRangePadding]
```

Here are outputs for different *Mathematica* versions (obtained on Windows 7 x64):

- version 11.0.0:

  ```
  {{"XTicksRange", {{0, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0, 1.05556}}}}
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}
  ```
- versions 10.4.1 and 10.0.1:

  ```
  {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}}
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}
  ```
- version 8.0.4:

  ```
  {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}}
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}
  ```

Let ut play with the lower bound of the plot range:

```
Reap[Rasterize@
      Plot[x, {x, #, 1}, 
       Ticks -> {Sow[{##}, "XTicksRange"] &, Sow[{##}, "YTicksRange"] &}], _, 
     List][[2]] & /@ {-10^-50, 0, 10^-2, 10^-1, .5} // Column
```

Here is output from version 11.0.0:

> ```
> {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0, 1.05556}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0, 1.02063}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0.1, 1.01875}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0.5, 1.01042}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0.5, 1.02778}}}}
> ```

And here is from version 10.4.1:

> ```
> {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{-0.010625, 1.02063}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0.08125, 1.01875}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}}
> {{"XTicksRange", {{0.489583, 1.01042}}}, {"YTicksRange", {{0.472222, 1.02778}}}}
> ```

Apparently in version 11.0.0 the calculation of the lower bound of the ticks range is changed for the situations when plot range starts from nonnegative value: the corresponding **`Scaled`** `PlotRangePadding` setting is ignored in such situations (note that absolute `PlotRangePadding` works as expected!). This change introduces inconsistency and contradicts the Documentation both for `Ticks` and for `PlotRangePadding`, hence I would consider it as a bug. Here is an illustration (`SetAttributes[NumberForm, NHoldRest]` is for fixing the bug described in the previous section):

```
SetAttributes[NumberForm, NHoldRest]
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.5], Scaled[.02]}, {Scaled[.5], Scaled[.02]}}]
```

> [image: plot]

The workaround is to use absolute `PlotRangePadding` specification:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{1.021, .021}, {1.021, .056}}]
```

> [image: plot]