# How to Control Tick Precision in ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I control the number of decimal places the ticks show along the horizontal and vertical axes? I have tried various approaches but ListLinePlot seems to automate it.

```
     r=2;NN=10;y0=0.1;
sol = RecurrenceTable[{y[k + 1] == r*y[k]*(1 - y[k]), y[0] == y0}, y, {k, 0, NN}]; AA = ListLinePlot[sol, Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0},  DataRange -> {0, NN} , 
PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0015], Blue}, PointSize[0.021]}];
BB = Plot[(r - 1)/r, {x, 0, NN}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0025], Red}}];
Show[AA, BB, Ticks -> {Range[0, NN, 1], Range[0, 1, 0.05]}]
```

Comment: Does this Q&A solve your problem: [How to make frame ticks' labels have same number of digits after decimal point?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125996/41569)

Comment: ListLinePlot ignores it. It seems more complicated than it should be; Excel does it with one setting. Mathematica seems more tricky ... any advice is welcomed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the number of decimal places displayed on the horizontal and vertical axes in a `ListLinePlot` or any other plot in Mathematica, you can use the `NumberForm` function within the `Ticks` option. Here's how you can modify your existing code to control the number of decimal places for the tick labels:

```
r = 2; NN = 10; y0 = 0.1;

sol = RecurrenceTable[{y[k + 1] == r*y[k]*(1 - y[k]), y[0] == y0}, 
   y, {k, 0, NN}];

AA = ListLinePlot[sol, Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
   DataRange -> {0, NN}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0015], Blue}, PointSize[0.021]}, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, 
     Table[{i, NumberForm[i, {2, 1}]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.05}]}];

BB = Plot[(r - 1)/r, {x, 0, NN}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0025], Red}}];

Show[AA, BB, Ticks -> {Range[0, NN, 1], Range[0, 1, 0.05]}]
```

Comment: wonderful ... many thanks Athanasios!

Answer (score 1):

Use pairs of values and print formats eg

```
ListLinePlot[Array[({#*\[Pi]/77.2, 12 E^(1/#)} &), {22}], 
Ticks -> 
 {({#, Style[ScientificForm[ #, 3], 6]} &) /@  Range[0, 1,  0.3389076], 
  ({#, Style[AccountingForm[ #, {4, 2}], 4]} &) /@ Range[10, 20, 0.987654321]}]
```

[image: Ticks formatting]

Comment: How to apply this to my code?